# How to query that shows counts of 2 different columns in the same table?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables TypeOfFruit and Fruit (That has a FK of TypeOfFruit) as seen below:

TypeOfFruit

```
ID      Name
1       Apples
2       Bananas
```

Fruit

```
ID      TypeId      Expired
1       1           FALSE
2       1           TRUE
3       1           TRUE
```

Basically I want to create a view with the following :

```
FruitStats

Name        total_num       total_expired
Apples      3           2
Bananas     0           0
```

with the first number being the total number of each type of fruit, and the 2nd number being JUST the number of expired fruit of that type.

I have come up with the following to get total_num:

```
CREATE VIEW Fruit_Stats (name, total_num) 
AS SELECT t.name, COUNT(f.id)
FROM TypeOfFruits t LEFT OUTER JOIN Fruits f ON f.type_id = t.id GROUP BY (t.id);
```

But am having trouble calculating expired in addition to that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. A `CASE` statement will get you what you need here:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(f.id), SUM(CASE WHEN expired = "TRUE" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_expired
FROM TypeOfFruits t LEFT OUTER JOIN Fruits f ON f.type_id = t.id GROUP BY (t.id);
```